# Permutation Matrix to change representation from column major to row major in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation, row-major-order, column-major-order

I have a 2D array in Matlab that needs to be converted to 1D, and Matlab uses column major representation for the conversion. However, I'd like to use a doubly stochastic matrix to convert the representation to row major.

For example, I have the following 2D array:

```
M = [1,2,3;4,5,6]
```

If I use reshape to represent it in 1D

```
v1 = reshape(M,size(M,1)*size(M,2),1)
```

I get a column major representation:

```
v1 = [1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

However, I'd like to use a permutation matrix like this:

```
A = [1,0,0,0,0,0;
    0,0,1,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,1,0;
    0,1,0,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,1,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,0,1];
```

so that I get the following row major representation:

```
v2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]'
```

by doing

```
v2 = A*v1
```

I know that I can get v2 by just doing

```
v2 = reshape(M',size(M,1)*size(M,2),1)
```

But I am particular about generating the permutation matrix in order to convert to row major representation.

If someone could help me generate this permutation matrix, it would really help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know why you want this permutation matrix. It's a whole lot less efficient than simply permuting your matrix. If you can explain why you are particular about it, it might be easier to help. I have a hard time helping people go in the wrong direction. ;)

Comment: By the way, your statement `reshape(M,size(M,1)*size(M,2),1)` can be written as `reshape(M,[],1)` or as `M(:)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm implementing a paper that uses the permutation matrix to change the representation. Since it involves optimization steps that make use of the matrix, it's easiest to just build the matrix and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your matrix `A` using linear indexing. Elements in a matrix can be indexed with one index, they are then addressed column-wise, in the same order in which they appear when reshaping the matrix to a vector.

You need to set an element in each odd column, where the element is one down from the previous column:

```
n = numel(M);
A = zeros(n,n);
A(1:2*n+1:end) = 1;
```

And also one in each even column in a similar way:

```
A(n+n/2+1:2*n+1:end) = 1;
```

This works for all matrices `M` with two rows. For a matrix with `m` rows:

```
[m,k] = size(M);
n = numel(M); % == m*k
index = 1:m*n+1:n*n;
offset = 0:n+k:m*n;
index = index + offset'; % requires newer MATLAB
A = zeros(n,n);
A(index(:)) = 1;
```

If the line that requires newer version of MATLAB gives you an error, replace with `bsxfun(@plus,index,offset')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
ind = reshape(1:numel(M), size(M,1), []).';
A = accumarray([(1:numel(M)).' ind(:)], 1);
```

Note also that your code

> `v2 = reshape(M',size(M,1)*size(M,2),1)`

will fail if `M` is complex. To transpose, use `.'` instead of `'`.

Comment: Quite a bit shorter than my version. Nice!